# Fitting Lines into a Grid Matrix [Competition , Not HW]

Tags: algorithm, matrix, 2d, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

In a recent competition organized by "AmDocs" , I came across the following question : (The basic Idea of the question)

You are a given a matrix of fixed size 12x12. 
You are given six line segments of length 6,5,5,4,3,2. 
The matrix has empty spaces and filled spaces. 
You have to return "Yes" Or "No" , whether all the 6 line segments can be fit into the matrix simultaneously or not. 
The lines can be placed horizontally or vertically Only.

What algorithm should be used to solve this problem ? Packing ? Knapsack ?

Comment: Do you have any time restrictions? Usual backtracking seems to solve this task well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would map the problem to SAT and use a SAT solver.  There is a pretty natural mapping.  Define the variables:

```
x_s_i_j_d = segment s starts at coordinates (i,j) and goes in direction d
```

(d is "right" or "down")

First, iterate over all the segments and starting positions, and see which are viable given the starting matrix.
example, M:

```
000000000000
111111111111
...
```

if segment 1 is length 2, then `L_seg1_0_0_down = false`, because it hits a filled space.

Then, write clauses that prohibit two crossing segments.  If segment 1 and segment 2 are both length 2, then we add the clause:

```
(!L_seg1_0_0_right || !L_seg2_1_0_right)
```

because if segment 1 uses coordinates (0,0), and (1,0), then segment 2 can't use (1,0) also.

finally, add the condition that each segment must be used at least once:

```
(L_seg1_0_0_right || L_seg1_0_1_right || ...)
```

for all the positions that seg1 can go.  Then throw your favorite SAT solver at it.

Comment: +1, the idea to map it to SAT is amazing. It gives the solution method, and prooves that this problem is NP-complete so it has no polinomial solution. About the performance: can you imagine what size will the result expression have?? Using solution in terms of logical expression can vastly slow down the program. I think that usial backtracking will give much better performance

Comment: @dvvrd: This does *not* prove NP-completeness, the (hard) reduction needs to go the other way.

Comment: @dvvrd: the backtracking inside the SAT solver will likely be identical to the backtracking in a straightforward solution.

Comment: When you turn this problem to SAT you lose initial semantics. I mean that some optimizations that are natural for this problem are unreachable in teerms of SAT problem

Answer (score 0):

I would use a greedy fill algorithm such as the following:

```
for largest_line to smallest_line do
  for first_empty_square_in_matrix to last_empty_square_in_matrix do
    if line_fits_horizontal then
      place_line
      break
    else if_line_fits_vertical then
      place_line
      break
if all_lines_placed then
  write('Yes')
else
  write('No')
```

To optimise the above you might note that if a horizontal line of length n fails to fit at position (i,j) then you won't need to test for it fitting horizontally at any of (i+1,j),(i+2,j)...(i+n,j).

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:
Iterate over all 2D array points and create collection of available segments. On each step you gonna analyse i-1 and j-1 cells and if you have segments which contains that cells you will increase their length (obviously you could find at most two segments).
After that you should put your arrays into available segments, so after every insert you should analyse all remaining segments and if any of them intersects with currently inserted you should decrease their size or split on two.